# Apache encoding URI causing 404s

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is a strange issue I'm having. I am using a framework that is called after mod_rewrite rewrites the URL. If a character in the URI is accented, as in the Latin alphabet, the request is never sent to my framework, but rather, the server errors out with a 404. I'm using a Windows machine, so not sure if this has something to do with it or not. As long as there are NO accented characters in the URI, then the request is sent to the framework without any issues. Can someone please tell me what's going on here and how to solve this?

**EDIT:** Here are 2 lines from my access.log. The first line shows the 404 where the accented `Å` was encoded by Apache and was not passed. When I change the `Å` in the URI to an English "A", everything works as expected.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2017:13:50:50 -0400] "GET /actor/%C3%85ker HTTP/1.1" 404 222
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2017:13:54:48 -0400] "GET /actor/Aker HTTP/1.1" 200 5701
```

**EDIT:**
These are the lines in the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is part of a debug log consisting of 2 people that shows that for one of them, mod_rewrite is not forwarding the request to my framework, yet the other is.

This is the one that fails:

```
[Fri Oct 20 17:52:48.119655 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52846] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1fec230/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] add path info postfix: C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor -> C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor/\xc3\x85kerman, referer: http://ansac.com/
[Fri Oct 20 17:52:48.119655 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52846] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1fec230/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor/\xc3\x85kerman -> actor/\xc3\x85kerman, referer: http://ansac.com/
[Fri Oct 20 17:52:48.119655 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52846] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1fec230/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'actor/\xc3\x85kerman', referer: http://ansac.com/
[Fri Oct 20 17:52:48.119655 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52846] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1fec230/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] pass through C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor, referer: http://ansac.com/
```

Strangely, this one works:

```
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] add path info postfix: C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor -> C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor/Gonz\xc3\xa1lez
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor/Gonz\xc3\xa1lez -> actor/Gonz\xc3\xa1lez
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'actor/Gonz\xc3\xa1lez'
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/actor' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] rewrite 'actor/Gonz\xc3\xa1lez' -> 'index.php?do=actor/Gonz\xc3\xa1lez'
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] split uri=index.php?do=actor/Gonz\xc3\xa1lez -> uri=index.php, args=do=actor/Gonz\xc3\xa1lez
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/index.php
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] strip document_root prefix: C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/index.php -> /index.php
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ff8290/initial] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ffd7c0/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/index.php -> index.php
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ffd7c0/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ffd7c0/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[Fri Oct 20 17:56:42.415807 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1620:tid 792] mod_rewrite.c(480): [client 127.0.0.1:52856] 127.0.0.1 - - [ansac.com/sid#2de668][rid#1ffd7c0/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/] pass through C:/Development/Apache24/htdocs/ansac/index.php
```

**Why does one work and not the other? Both names have accents in them, yet one fails.**

Comment: apache does not encode anything afaik, its your browser.

Comment: I think you're right, the browser is encoding the URI. When the link is passed to the URI, I need Apache to send that encoded string back to my framework where I can decode it. The issue is that the server errors out before my framework ever gets it. I think this is a mod_rewrite issue.

Comment: "the request is never sent to my framework" - Please include the relevant directives from your server config and/or `.htaccess` file that sends the request to your framework. If mod_rewrite only rewrites "word characters" (ie. `\w`) for example, then it will not reach your framework.

Comment: I've posted the contents of the htaccess file above. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hypothesis...

> ```
> RewriteRule .* index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

This line *looks* like an error, since the `$1` backreference will *always* be empty as there is no captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The "framework" may still work (for the Latin alphabet) because it may be parsing the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal instead (as a fallback perhaps) - which many frameworks do. However, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will remain URL encoded (eg. `/actor/%C3%85ker`) - so this probably needs to be URL decoded (eg. `/actor/Åker`) before it can be routed through your framework. This might be where the problem is. A request like `/actor/Aker`, on the other hand, is the same whether it's URL encoded or not, so this would not affect URLs like this.

However, if your framework allows the requested URL to be overridden with the `request` URL parameter then consider changing the above directive to:

```
 RewriteRule (.*) index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

ie. enclose the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in parentheses.

This will result in the captured URL-path being passed in the `request` URL parameter. Now, the important difference with this is that the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` directive matches against is already URL decoded. So, the `request` URL parameter already contains the URL-decoded request (albeit less the slash prefix), eg. `actor/Åker`.

---

**UPDATE:** Try changing the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `.*` to `[\s\S]*` instead. For example:

```
 RewriteRule ([\s\S]*) index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is just a slightly more encompassing pattern. Whilst `.` (dot) matches any-character (excluding newlines), `[\s\S]` matches any whitespace and any non-whitespace characters (ie. *everything*).

Comment: Thanks, MrWhite. Unfortunately, the behavior still exists even after adding the parens. I've found a thread that talks about using the "B" and "NE" flags but I'm not certain they are pertinent to my my issue. I've tried both, and a combination of them but it still isn't helping. Unfortunately, I'm out of my knowledge base on this issue. Is there anything else that you can suggest?

Comment: It seems to me that Apache is 404ing because it's looking for a file or directory matching the encoded string, which of course doesn't exist. If I could only get mod_rewrite to just pass PHP the value, I can decode it on the application side and do what I need with it.

Comment: The `B` flag would URL encode the captured URL-path, so you'd essentially be back to square one (the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` variable will now be URL encoded). Although PHP automatically decodes the `$_GET` array (URL parameters), so that would probably "fix" it (if this was being used by the framework). The `NE` (`noescape`) flag would not seem to be relevant here. Unfortunately, without knowing how the framework works, or more about your system it's difficult to know where to go from here. There would seem to be an encoding issue _somewhere_. Database encoding? Framework unicode support?

Comment: "If I could only get mod_rewrite to just pass PHP the value" - In your original directives, mod_rewrite isn't actually passing anything. Are you saying that `index.php` is not even being invoked? The 404 you are seeing - is that generated by your framework or Apache?

Comment: The thing is, I have *everything* set to use utf8; the database and the HTML. In the case of the (for the lack of proper terminology) "accented characters" I'm storing them in the database as utf8 decoded. I'm not sure if this is right or wrong, but I have found this to be acceptable with everything in the system being utf8 compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the flags. I read the docs but didn't really understand what it was talking about. You clarified them for me, so thank you again for that. It seems that I'm missing a rewrite condition. I'm just thinking aloud here, but when the URI has one of these accented characters in it, the request never makes it to my framework. The framework picks up the value (URI) passed to it, but the server just 404s and doesn't send PHP the URI. This is why I think I may need a rewrite condition.

Comment: The 404 I'm seeing is from Apache, NOT from my framework. Sorry, I just saw your question. I know this because I cannot echo the `$_GET` request from the first line of the index.php file.

Comment: Ok, that is weird. There is nothing with these mod_rewrite directives that would prevent the request from reaching your framework - there are no extra conditions you can add to help here. Do you have any other directives? Other `.htaccess` files, etc.? Anything reported in your error log? You should enable mod_rewrite debugging if not already (eg. `LogLevel rewrite:debug` in server config). If this request is not even reaching your framework then there would seem to be _something else_ blocking this _before_ mod_rewrite gets to route the request!?

Comment: No, the entire contents of the htaccess file is what I posted above. I have LogLevel set but honestly, I don't know how to read it. If you feel like deciphering it, I'm happy to post it for you. I can tell you though, I'm 100% certain that the 404s are being generated by Apache and that my framework is not receiving the value. I don't think it's being sent at all.

Comment: MrWhite, for what it's worth, I enabled debugging and I ran 2 tests; on one link that the browser doesn't encode, that works (PHP receives the GET request), and the last one on the link that the browser does encode that fails (No rewrite). I compared both blocks of of the error.log and the difference between the two is the one that is not being forwarded to my framework says `pass through`, while the link that does work says `rewrite`. Does that help at all?

Comment: Can you add that section of the log to your question, including the rest of that line and the preceding lines. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, will do it now, thanks again for looking at this. I think when you see the debug log that you'll agree, something is amiss as the value isn't being sent to my index.php file.

Comment: Did you change the `RewriteRule` directive to something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]`?

Comment: You mean that now uses parens? Yes, my RewriteRule looks exactly like what you've just posted.

Comment: Try changing the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ from `^(.*)$` to `([\s\S]*)`. Or even try simply `^` - although this won't capture the pattern (but neither did your original directive). I've updated my answer.

Comment: `([\s\S]*)` flipping works!!!! Why? Why doesn't `(.*)` catch it??

Comment: Wow - good! I've added a bit more explanation to my answer, but basically, `[\s\S]*` is just a more inclusive regex - it matches more characters than `.*`, which notably excludes newlines and quite possibly "some other" characters (it seems). From your log it seemed the original `.*` pattern wasn't matching. Although I did test that on my own server and it worked OK - maybe a subtle difference in regex engine versions?

Comment: Just for fun, I tried just `^` and it doesn't work. I get a page refresh but am not taken to the link. There is however, no 404. So, you are matching any whitespace and non-whitespace character. I still don't understand why `(.*)` will not match any URL encoded string...

Comment: This is good to know, thank you! I'm certainly no regex expert by any stretch, but I was always under the impression that `(.*)` matched anything and everything. Again, good knowledge to have. You saved the day my friend! I'd buy you a cup if you were close by. Thanks for all your help and dedication!

Comment: Specifically, I wonder if the issue was that `.` won't match byte 0x85 depending on the compilation options used with your PCRE library. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31216840/107331

Comment: @DanielMartin Interesting, that could well have been the issue. However, I was unable to reproduce this on my system (also Apache 2.4 / Windows - although no doubt _exact_ versions probably varied).

Answer (score 0):

1. Look in your logs. What is the path to the file that the Apache
   error log says it is looking for? Does this path to this file exist?
2. This sounds like a character encoding problem. Ensure the character
   encoding is configured in Apache appropriately. Unfortunately, I
   don't have a specific recommendation for that.